# Highly asymmetric regular graph

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings

Let $G$ be a regular connected simple graph on $n$ vertices with chromatic number $\chi$ and maximum degree $\Delta$. Then, it is implied that $G$ is $\chi$-partite. Suppose, we remove one of the partite set of vertices. Then, what would  be the maximum degree of the induced subgraph formed by the remaining vertices?

I may say with some  confidence that the induced subgraph would have a maximum degree of $\textit{at least} $ $\chi-2$(as the remaining partite sets must be connected with each other, otherwise the graph would be disconnected). In addition, if the graph be vertex transitive, I think that the maximum degree of the induced subgraph would be $\Delta-1$. Any hints and counterexamples in this case? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: What about a 5-cycle?

Comment: @GordonRoyle yes, 5-cycle satisfies the criterion of having any induced subgraph(formed by removing ine part of independent vertices) having degree $\chi-2=3-2=$. I think this straight from the fact that $\chi\le\Delta+1$ for any graph(therefore the induced subgraph, which has $\chi-1$ as its chromatic number should have at least $\chi-2$ as the degree)

Comment: @GordonRoyle by the way, if you meant that the $5$-cycle has a disconnected graph when one partite set is removed, then I agree on that point

Comment: I don't understand your answer to Gordon. A $5$-cycle is vertex-transitive with $\Delta=2$ and $\chi=3$. If you remove a color class with a single vertex, the induced subgraph still has maximum degree $2$, so this is a counterexample.

Comment: At the other end, if you take say a balanced multipartite graph (which is vertex-transitive), with $\chi$ parts of size $k$, then $\Delta=(\chi-1)k$, where one you delete a part, the maximum degree will be $(\chi-2)k$, so the difference can be arbitrarily large.

Comment: @verret as for your $5-$cycle case, i hope you too missed the $\textit{at least}$ point, which i recently edited

Comment: @vidyarthi No, I didn't miss it. Whether that part is true or not (it's hard to tell because it's poorly written), in the next sentence you say "in addition". That part is clearly wrong.

Comment: @verret ok, I agree that the part that vertex transitive have induced subgraphs of maximum degree $\Delta-2$ is wrong. But, my first confident claim is right, I hope, because; since the chromatic number of the induced subgraph is $\chi-1$(as one independent set is removed from $\chi$ sets), so its maximum degree has to be greater than or equal to $\chi-2$, right?

Comment: Yes, that's obvious: the new graph has chromatic number $\chi'=\chi-1$ so its maximum degree $\Delta'$ satisfies $\Delta'\geq \chi'-1=\chi-2$. (I still don't understand your parenthetical remark about being "connected with each other", which is why I mostly ignored this part of  your question.)

Comment: So basically, we're left with an obvious observation and a conjecture disproved by a $5$-cycle. I don't think is research level. It would fit better on stackexchange.

Comment: @verret maybe. But at the time of asking, it actually arose from a research note I was writing. And, by the way, I dont see quick response for graph theory questions at math.SE. In that sense, most of the questions I asked were not too abstruse, yet not easy to be answered in math.SE, I hope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a complete $k$-partite graph $G$ where all parts have size $n/k >> k$. Then $\Delta = n(k-1)/k$, and even after removing a part the degree would still be $n(k-2)/k$ $=\Delta - n/k$. [I am not sure precisely what you mean by 'highly symmetric but you surely could remove some of the edges so that there are no graph automorphisms, the minimum degree stays high, and there remains in there a copy of a complete $k$-partite graph on $m >>k$ vertices so the chromatic number stays $k$]

Comment: yes, but what do you mean by "neither"? I mean, even in your example, the maximum degree of the induced subgraph formed by removing one part still satisfies $\Delta\ge\chi-2=k-2$ as $\frac{n(k-2)}{k}\ge\frac{n}{k}\ge k$

Comment: I didn't register the "at least" part before, my mistake

Comment: no problem, I just edited the question.